# Close Stateflow editor programmatically

Tags: matlab, window-management, stateflow

Is there a way to close (or hide) a Stateflow Editor programmatically?

I could not find any hint about this in the documentation or the net. The only way I know of is to close the model entirely, but I do not want this, as a changed model might need to be saved beforehand, so user interaction is needed.

Here's a simple example what I am currently doing:

```
sfr = sfroot;
% For simplicity I assume exactly one chart is found
chart = sfr.find('-isa', 'Stateflow.Chart');
% This can be used to display a chart
chart.view;
% How can the shown Stateflow Editor be closed again?
```

Now the `chart` object has an `Editor` property. But neither this nor the chart object itself have any useful member functions.

I am not bound on a specific Matlab release, so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There actually is a Matlab command called `sfclose` which allows to close a Stateflow chart.

Without arguments the currently active chart is closed. To close a specific chart, its name has to be passed. The name consists of the full path excluding the model name. To close the chart `model/sys1/sys2/chart` the command is as follows:

```
sfclose('sys1/sys2/chart')
```

*Note: Unfortunately this command can only be found in the documentation if the phrase "sfclose" or "close chart" is searched. Anything else leads to unrelated results.*